# My python recursive function won't return and exceeds maximum recursive depth

Tags: python, recursion

I simply do not understand why this is not returning the value and stopping the recursion. I have tried everything but it seems to just keep on going no matter what I do. I am trying to get the program to get the loop to compare the first two values of the list if they are the same return that it was the first value. If they were not, add the first and second values of each list and compare, etc etc until it reaches the end of the list. If the sum of the values in each list never equal each other at any point then return 0.

It is supposed to take three inputs:

1. A single integer defining the length of the next two inputs
2. First set of input data
3. Second set of input data

Ex input

3

1     3 3

2     2 2

It should output a single number. In the case of the example data, it should output 2 because the sum of the lists equalled at the second value.

```
N = int(input())
s1 = input().split()
s2 = input().split()
count = 0

def func1(x,y):
        if x == y:
            return(count)
        elif (N - 1) == count:
            return(0)
        else:
            count + 1
            return(func1(x + int(s1[count]), y + int(s2[count])))

days = func1(int(s1[0]),int(s2[0]))
print(days)
```

I am sorry in advance if I really messed up the formatting or made some dumb mistake, I am pretty new to programming and I have never posted on here before. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This problem does not require recursion.

Comment: `count` is actually never updated, `count + 1` does nothing.

Comment: agreed with @AKX. Are you trying to do recursion as a learning exercise?

Comment: @AKX How would you go about solving this problem then? and even if it does not require recursion, I am trying to figure out why it is not working as it should work even if not required right? I understand it is likely not the easiest method to solve the problem but it is the one I chose to go with.

Comment: `return` isn’t a function in Python, don’t put parentheses around its value.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think `return` (as "the instruction that ends a function's execution at this point and eventually defines the returned value") is a function in any programming language - else you'd have a chicken and egg situation xD

Comment: @bereal I should have known better - you can alway count on Haskell to prove you wrong xD

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I had to revoke that comment though, because `return` does not end a function's execution in Haskell, so you're correct.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It is in R (it also is in Haskell, but it means something fundamentally different there so I don’t count that) and potentially also in some Scheme/Lisp dialect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never actually update the variable `count`. However, just writing:

```
count += 1
```

is not going to work either without declaring the variable global:

```
def func1(x, y):
    global count
    ....
```

That said, global variables increase code complexity and break re-enterability, i.e. the same function can no longer be called twice, not to mention about concurrency. A much cleaner way is to make `count` a function argument, it will look like this (the code not tested and is here for illustration only):

```
N = int(input())
s1 = [int(c) for c in input().split()]
s2 = [int(c) for c in input().split()]

def func1(x, y, count=0):
    if x == y:
        return count
    elif count == N - 1:
        return 0
    else:
        return(func1(x + s1[count], y + s2[count]), count + 1)

days = func1(int(s1[0]),int(s2[0]))
print(days)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer "How would you go about solving this problem then" – If I understood the problem correctly, the aim is to find the index where the "running total" of the two lists is the same. If so,

```py
def func1(s1, s2):
    total_a = 0
    total_b = 0
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)):
        total_a += a
        total_b += b
        if total_a == total_b:
            return i
    return 0


print(func1([1, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2]))
```

does the trick. (I've elided the input bits here – this function just works with two lists of integers.)